# Arrays, going from MySQLi to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, mysqli

A couple years ago, SO users helped me construct the following code to assign "partners" for in a group (like a round robin [A->B->C->D->A->B->...]):

```
$q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE group_id='$gi' ORDER BY RAND()";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        $users[] = $row[0];
    }

    $current = end($users);
    $partners = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $partners[$user] = $current;
        $current = $user;
        $q="UPDATE users SET partner='{$partners[$user]}' WHERE user_id='{$user}'";
        mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    }
```

Now, however, I am rewriting much of my code with PDO, and arrays are killing me.  This is my best attempt so far at rewriting this:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE gid=:gid ORDER BY RAND()";
$query_params = array( ':gid' => $_SESSION['user']['gid'] );
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) {   
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) {
$users[] = $row[0];
}
$current = end($users);
$partners = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $partners[$user] = $current;
    $current = $user;
    $query = "UPDATE users SET partner=:partner WHERE id=:id";
    $query_params = array(
        ':partner' => '{$partners[$user]}',
        ':id' => '{$user}'
    );

    try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

All my reading and searching has not yielded an answer as to why my revised code no longer works.  **All that happens now is that the one user gets assigned himself as partner, rather than a round robin assignment of partners.**

As best I can tell, my `fetchAll` statement is incorrect, but how?  I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out.

(And I won't be upset if you suggest a more efficient method of doing this whole thing.)

Comment: you're using pdo wrong. you should be using placeholders for the two variables you're inserting, prepare the statement ONCE, then execute it multiple times while providing the two values each time.

Comment: Marc B, I revised my code to use placeholders where missing, but that makes no difference as to the result.  I believe that the problem lies with the `fetchAll` or with the broader `while`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hour of scouring and tinkering and I happened upon the answer.  I don't know why it seems to be shared nowhere, but the PDO equivalent of `mysqli_fetch_array` is not universally `fetchAll`.  In this case, and many others, the proper substitute is `fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`.

So, my code now works exactly as above except for this one change:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $users[] = $row[0];
}
```

Instead of:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) {
    $users[] = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   ':id' => '{$user}'
```

is wrong. You're trying to insert a literal `{`, `$`, `u`, etc... into your query. it should be just

```
  ':id' => $user
```

and similarly for partner.

Remember... PHP does not interpolate variables in single-quoted strings.

Comment: Changed as suggested.  No difference in the result.  Again, all that happens when I run my PDO code now is that one user gets assigned himself as partner, as opposed to a circle of partners being assigned.

Comment: well, don't blame pdo. pdo does exactly what you tell it do. start debugging. output what you're doing at each stage, check that the variables are what you expect, etc...

Comment: I'm not blaming PDO.  I thought that `while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN))` would be equivalent to `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.